# Difference between 'Database Restore' & 'Database Migration'?

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to move my DB to Azure Managed Instance.

I would like to know what should I do about this.

I have the options of DB migration and DB restore to Azure managed instance.

Please let me know the difference between these 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you first do a full Backup and then migrate the Database.
If something go wrong then you Restore the Database.
But I don't know exactly how Azure M.I. works..

Comment: Cruz  If we have the backup then it is enough to restore the DB directly without going for migration. Right? Are there any special benefits for doing migration rather than restoring the DB directly?

Answer (score 0):

For database restore option; you can take a backup of your database and then you can restore that backup on the cloud if your application(s) or service(s) handle a moderate downtime or maybe you does not care about downtime. After the restoration you just need to redirect your database connections of your application(s) or service(s).

For the database migration; it is a little bit more complex. Generally, this option has been using for database systems which we do not want to take downtime on it. Also, for this option you will always need a database restoration(or initial load). After the restoration or inital load you just need your cloud database copy up to date. So, for this purpose the database logs which is generated on the source database systems are being applied on target database systems until you decide to switch cloud database systems.

PS: Of course, data volume is another critical aspects of database migration to the cloud.